# UIButton state image not updating on layoutIfNeeded

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I've some scenario that if button is on then show some view else show some else.
So, I need to update my constraints based on button's state change.
I've taken two images, switchOff and switchOn for normal and selected state respectively.
But selected state image is not showing up on selection of UIButton.
Here is my code for same.

```
@IBOutlet var switchMultiplePrice: UIButton!
...
@IBAction func btnMultiplePriceSelected(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let isSelected = switchMultiplePrice.isSelected
    switchMultiplePrice.isSelected = !isSelected
    constMultiplePriceViewBottom.isActive = isSelected
    constSinglePriceViewBottom.isActive = !isSelected
    constGuidePriceViewHeight.constant = isSelected ? 46.0 : 0.0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
        self.singlePriceView.isHidden = isSelected
        self.multiplePriceView.isHidden = !isSelected
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

But selected state image is not appearing. If I comment just below line then UIButton's image is perfect working for selected and normal state.

```
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

I know if I comment upper line then my constrains will not be updated.
What can I do in this scenario.

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: `DispatchQueue.main.async {
       //Add your UI update code     
 }`

Comment: @Paresh.P , not animating on updates of `constGuidePriceViewHeight.constant`.

Comment: try self.view.layoutSubview() it will compulsory layout the view.